# How can you define a 2-D Quantity Array in Python with different units in each dimension

Tags: python, numpy, units-of-measurement, pint

I want to define an array containing fuel consumption data for a genset.  The x-axis will have units of 'kW' and the y-axis 'gal/hr'.  Is there a way to create a Numpy compatible Quantity Array with Pint or a similar library that has different dimensions in each axis?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  `different units in each dimension`?  `different dimensions in each axis`?  Plotting `kW` on the x-axis, and `gal/hr` on the y makes some sense, but that's plotting two 1d arrays against each other, not a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I've found is to use the experimental pint-pandas library and storing the data as a data-frame.

```
consumption_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "power": pd.Series([5, 10, 15, 20], dtype="pint[kW]"),
    "consumption": pd.Series([0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.6], dtype="pint[gal/hr]")})
```